# Join query in MySQL cursor

Tags: mysql, join, cursor

We can declare a cursor like this

```
DECLARE cur1 CURSOR FOR SELECT id,data FROM test.t1;
```

Can we use a join query instead of a simple query?

Comment: Can you describe what problem you are trying to solve instead of how you are trying to solve it? The question in its current form is probably unanswerable.

Comment: I want to say can I use "DECLARE cur1 CURSOR FOR SELECT * from t1 inner join t2 using(c1);"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can use all the various clauses in the SELECT statement except the "INTO" clause.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/declare-cursor.html

Answer (score 0):

The simple answer is yes.  You can you a join query when declaring a cursor.